# Apache Kafka Cluster start fails with NoNodeException

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to start a spark streaming session which consumes from a Kafka queue and I'm using Zookeeper for config mgt. However, when I try to start this following exception is being thrown.

```
18/03/26 09:25:49 INFO ZookeeperConnection: Checking Kafka topic core-data-tickets does exists ...

18/03/26 09:25:49 INFO Broker: Kafka topic core-data-tickets exists
18/03/26 09:25:49 INFO Broker: Processing topic : core-data-tickets
18/03/26 09:25:49 WARN ZookeeperConnection: Resetting Topic Offset
org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkNoNodeException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /consumers/clt/offsets/core-data-tickets/4
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkException.create(ZkException.java:47)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.retryUntilConnected(ZkClient.java:685)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.readData(ZkClient.java:766)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.readData(ZkClient.java:761)
    at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.readData(ZkUtils.scala:443)
    at kafka.utils.ZkUtils.readData(ZkUtils.scala)
    at net.core.data.connection.ZookeeperConnection.readTopicPartitionOffset(ZookeeperConnection.java:145)
```

I have already created the relevant Kafka topic.

Any insights on this would be highly appreciated.

#

I'm using the following code to run the spark job

```
spark-submit --class net.core.data.compute.Broker     --executor-memory 512M     --total-executor-cores 2     --driver-java-options "-Dproperties.path=/ebs/tmp/continuous-loading-tool/continuous-loading-tool/src/main/resources/dev.properties"  --conf spark.ui.port=4045   /ebs/tmp/dev/data/continuous-loading-tool/target/continuous-loading-tool-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: Can you post the command that causes this error?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous updated

Comment: When was the last time the group has committed offsets and what is the value of `offsets.retention.minutes` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that this error has to do with offsets retention. By default, offsets are stored for only 1440 minutes (i.e. 24 hours). Therefore, if the group has not committed offsets within a day, Kafka won't have information about it.

A possible workaround is to set the value of `offsets.retention.minutes` accordingly.

**[offsets.retention.minutes](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs)**

> Offsets older than this retention period will be discarded

Comment: the 'offsets.retention.minutes=86400000'

Comment: In ZK terminal, what is the response from `ls /consumers/clt/offsets/core-data-tickets/4` ?

Comment: I'm getting this [zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 4] ls /consumers/clt/offsets/core-data-tickets/4
[]

Comment: Anyways, I manually created the core-data-tickets/4 and it worked.. Thanks man for guiding me through